Formal argument "palette" matched by multiple actual arguments?
I recently updated to R version 4.4.0, which I'm using through RStudio (2024.04.0+735). ggplot2 won't let me add a palette anymore and I'm going crazy.
Where is this ghost palette coming from? How can I get rid of the error?
In a fresh session with no attached packages, the following code produces an error:
ggplot2::ggplot() + ggplot2::scale_color_manual(palette = function(n) n)

The error reads:

Error in discrete_scale(aesthetic, name = name, palette = pal, breaks = breaks,  :
formal argument "palette" matched by multiple actual arguments

Session info:
R version 4.4.0 (2024-04-24)
Platform: aarch64-apple-darwin20
Running under: macOS Sonoma 14.0

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib 
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.4-arm64/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib;  LAPACK version 3.12.0

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

time zone: Asia/Jerusalem
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] utf8_1.2.4        R6_2.5.1          tidyselect_1.2.1  magrittr_2.0.3   
 [5] gtable_0.3.5      glue_1.7.0        tibble_3.2.1      pkgconfig_2.0.3  
 [9] generics_0.1.3    dplyr_1.1.4       lifecycle_1.0.4   ggplot2_3.5.1    
[13] cli_3.6.2         fansi_1.0.6       scales_1.3.0      grid_4.4.0       
[17] vctrs_0.6.5       compiler_4.4.0    rstudioapi_0.16.0 tools_4.4.0      
[21] munsell_0.5.1     pillar_1.9.0      colorspace_2.1-0  rlang_1.1.3      


Related links: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/5625, https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/3182 . I'm surprised that this ever worked for you: how old was the version you've upgraded from?

@BenBolker thank you! I'm not sure how old my previous version was, but I'm glad to be updated now. Switched to using values instead and all working fine.

Feel free to post an answer to your own question using this information.
